# How to fix admin blank page issue in magento 2.3.x in XAMP

Tags: magento, magento2

Blank page when I try to login admin panel

XAMP 3.2.4, Magento 2.3.2, PHP 7.2.21

No error message displaying. Only Dark Blank Page.

Comment: remove the uncomment line like this ini_set('display_errors', 1); in app/bootstrap.php and rename the local.xml.sample to local.xml in pub/errors. Then send me the error message I can help you

Answer (score 1):

check log file

/var/logs/exceptions.log

or other log files in same folder they should give you details about issue you have

or enable developer mode in magento and error display